# Screen timeout/lock script

Tags: bash, linux, timeout

This is a script I made while having trouble with xautolock and dimming of the screen right before locking it. I would like some tips for making it a bit more robust and to know of any disadvantages of it. I don't know how it works with multiple screens but I suspect it does not.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Lock screen in:
minutes=15
seconds=0

# How many seconds it takes to dim
dim_secs=5

idle_secs=$(( $minutes * 60 + $seconds )) # Screen timeout in seconds
idle_ms=$(( $idle_secs * 1000 ))

timeout=$idle_secs

while true; do
    sleep $timeout

    if pgrep xflock4 > /dev/null; then
        timeout=$idle_secs
        continue
    fi

    # After sleeping, check user idle time
    if [ $(xprintidle) -ge $idle_ms ]; then
        WINDOW=$(echo $(xwininfo -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) -stats | \
                        egrep '(Width|Height):' | \
                        awk '{print $NF}') | \
                sed -e 's/ /x/')
        SCREEN=$(xdpyinfo | grep -m1 dimensions | awk '{print $2}')

        # If greater than timeout check if something's not in fullscreen and active
        if [ "$WINDOW" != "$SCREEN" ]; then
            interrupted=false # If dimming's been interrupted

            screen=$(xrandr -q | grep " connected" | awk '{print $1;}') # Connected screen
            brightness=$(xrandr --verbose | grep -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' ') # Current brightness

            start_time=$(date "+%s.%N") # Current time
            while true; do
                # Current brightness(0 to $brigtness), decided by time since dimming started
                br=$(echo "$brightness-$brightness*(($(date "+%s.%N")-$start_time)/$dim_secs)" | bc -l)
                if [ $(echo "$br >= 0" | bc) -eq 1  ]; then
                    # Set the current brightness and sleep for a short while
                    xrandr --output $screen --brightness $br
                    sleep 0.01
                else
                    # If brightness is less than 0 then it means that the
                    # time since starting dimming is greater than $dim_secs
                    break
                fi

                # If the user gave an input that's less than $idle_ms
                # Will always be less than $idle_ms if it was interrupted during dimming
                if [ $(xprintidle) -lt $idle_ms ]; then
                    interrupted=true
                    break
                fi
            done
            if $interrupted; then
                # If it was interrupted during dimming, reset brightness
                xrandr --output $screen --brightness $brightness
            else
                xset dpms force off # Turn screen off
                xrandr --output $screen --brightness $brightness # Reset brightness

                xflock4 # Lock screen
            fi
        fi
    fi

    # Timeout before checking idle time again
    timeout=$(echo "$idle_secs - $(xprintidle) / 1000 " | bc -l)
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to prefix variables with `$` inside `$(( ... ))`,
this will work just as well:

```
idle_secs=$(( minutes * 60 + seconds ))  # Screen timeout in seconds
idle_ms=$(( idle_secs * 1000 ))
```

---

In many places you pipe to a `grep` and then pipe to `awk`.
Note that `awk` can perform many of the functions of `grep`,
and using one process (`awk`) instead of two (`grep` + `awk`) would be more optimal.

Here are some examples. Instead of:

> ```
> ... | egrep '(Width|Height):' | awk '{print $NF}'
> ```

This is equivalent:

```
... | awk '/(Width|Height):/ {print $NF}'
```

Instead of:

> ```
> ... | grep -m1 dimensions | awk '{print $2}'
> ```

This is equivalent:

```
... | awk '/dimensions/ {print $2; exit}'
```

And so on, similarly at other places too, you get the idea.

---

Another common pattern I see at many places:

> ```
> echo "$br >= 0" | bc -l
> ```

That is, using `echo` to pass a string to a command.
A better way is using *here-strings*, like this:

```
bc -l <<< "$br >= 0"
```

---

This long line appears at multiple places, sometimes with minor variations:

> ```
> # If it was interrupted during dimming, reset brightness
> xrandr --output $screen --brightness $brightness
> ```

It would be better to move this to a function,
for example `reset_brightness`,
to reduce duplication of logic.

Comment: I get "pgrep: invalid option -- 'q'"

Comment: Ah... Worked in my system (BSD version), looks like GNU version doesn't have it. Thanks, removed that point.